# Drupal 7 learning resources

Tags: drupal

I have to use Drupal for a project I will be working on.
Do you know any good training resources for Drupal 7?

Also I have good programming knowledge, and know a bit of PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Drupal Dojo, they have video sessions on a lot of subjects including Drupal 7: http://drupaldojo.com/sessions

If you want to dwelve deeper into programming your own modules or creating themes there's a couple of books out there targeting Drupal 7 but I can only recommend Pro Drupal 7 Development ( http://www.drupalbook.com/ ) as it's the only one I've looked at.

Answer (score 0):

To get started site-building and/or developing on Drupal 7 I would check out the dojo as someone said but also check out these resources:

For site-building:

- There are all kinds of helpful blog posts on the planet feed - subscribe to: http://drupal.org/planet/rss.xml
- Visit http://drupalize.me for many free training videos. I recommend signing up for a membership as it's cheap and very high-value training content

For module development and a better understanding of D7 internals

- Check out the book: [Drupal 7 Module Development](https://www.packtpub.com/drupal-7-module-development/book)
- Go download the [Examples For Developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples) modules as there is a ton of code examples you can use
- Visit http://api.drupal.org all the time

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has a high learning curve, if you don't know PHP really well its going to be even steeper. I'd suggest picking up a book on the subject because there just aren't enough good internet resources out there for someone who has no concept of Drupal.

This is my favorite book, I read their D6 book when I knew absolutely nothing about Drupal and I was coding custom modules less than a month later. They have an updated one for D7 already: [Pro Drupal 7 Development](http://apress.com/book/view/1430228385)